# Jquery does not trigger if statement for certain values

Tags: jquery

I have this very simple function that keep giving incorrect values for certain input and i can't see where it goes wrong.

When photocount is set to 20 to 59, the if statement is not triggered.
Values 60 and above and 19 and below work correct.

Example:

o_priceperphoto = 0.50

o_photocount = 30

o_maxphotoprice = 11

o_photoprice = 15 (and should be 11)

I have no idea why. Hope someone sees what goes wrong.

```
function photoprice(o){
  var priceperphoto = $('#o_priceperphoto').val();
  var photocount = $('#o_photocount').val();
  var maxphotoprice = $('#o_maxphotoprice').val();
  var photoprice = parseFloat(priceperphoto * photocount).toFixed(2);

  // 20 - 59 errors
  if(photoprice > maxphotoprice){
    $('#o_photoprice').val(maxphotoprice);
  }

};
```

Comment: `console.log()` absolutly everything, log every variable and you'll see where your code goes wrong

Comment: You're comparing a float and a string, not that it should really matter, but using the same type would at least make sure that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(parseFloat(photoprice) > parseFloat(maxphotoprice)){
  $('#o_photoprice').val(maxphotoprice);
}
```

Comment: i think use parseFloat instead of parseInt

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing float and string values

Typecast`parseFloat(photoprice)` and `parseFloat(maxphotoprice)`

```
function photoprice(o){
      var priceperphoto = $('#o_priceperphoto').val();
      var photocount = $('#o_photocount').val();
      var maxphotoprice = $('#o_maxphotoprice').val();
      var photoprice = parseFloat(priceperphoto * photocount).toFixed(2);

      // 20 - 59 errors
      if(parseFloat(photoprice) > parseFloat(maxphotoprice)){//need to typecast to float
        $('#o_photoprice').val(maxphotoprice);
      }

    };
```

you are comparing float and string values